# $||f*\mu||_1=||f||_1$ for all f implies $\mu$ degenerate

Tags: convolution

Show that $||f*\mu||_1=||f||_1$ for all $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ where $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ implies $\mu$ is degenerate. This is closely related to a recent post where it was shown that $\mu$ cannot be absolutely continuous. In his answer David Ullrich used continuity of translates in $L^{1}$. Since translation of a measure is continuous for weak convergence but not for total variation convergence a new proof is required.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Previous post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634026

Comment: what does 'degenerate' mean

Comment: Measures of the type $\delta_x$ defined by $\delta_x(E)=1$ if $x \in E$ and $0$ otherwise are called degenerate measures. @mathworker21

Comment: May I help you !!! cause I have seen this problem being discussed in an online maths discussion meet